# Is it possible to avoid using a double for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by

I have to use a double for loop to loop through the data to compare one row of data with the other rows. And I have to do this for each row.

Unfortunately my real data is millions of rows long and the loop is taking ages to process.

Is there a way to avoid using a double for loop? Since I am only interested in comparing Date1 and date2 for similar Things - I thought I could groupby Thing and apply the double for loop to each group?

But I wasn't sure how to write this because there was a complication with len(grouped). Also there are lots of rows where 'Quantity'=0 so those rows do not need to be included in the calculation. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    d={'Thing':['Thing1','Thing2','Thing1','Thing2','Thing5'],'Date1' : 
    ['01-01-2016','02-02-2015','03-03-2015','03-03-2015', '24-03-2016'], 'Date2' : ['04-04-2015','03-03-2014','05-04-2015','07-03-2015','03-04-2016'], 
    'Quantity':[1,1,1,1,0]}

    data=pd.DataFrame(d)

    data['Level']=0

    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(data)):
            if data['Thing'][i] == data['Thing'][j] and data['Date1'][i] >= data['Date1'][j] 
            and data['Date1'][i] < data['Date2'][j] and data['Quantity']==1:
                data['Level'][i]=data['Level'][i]+1 
                data['Level'][j]=data['Level'][j]+1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?? What's the code supposed to compare or update or?..

Comment: A rule of thumb: If you ever find yourself using `for` loops with pandas you're most probably doing something wrong.

Comment: First of all, never use normal `for`-loops in pandas, always use the builtin iterators, e.g. `iterrows` and index your rows using `loc` or `iloc`.

Comment: Date1 signifies arrival, date2 signifies departure - for every row I want to know how many of the same type of Thing is still in stock (has arrived but hasn't departed) when this item (row) arrives. Is that clearer? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to perform a self join:

```
merged_data = data.merge(data, on='Thing', how='outer')
```

the result looks like:

```
merged_data
      Date1_x     Date2_x  Quantity_x   Thing     Date1_y     Date2_y  \
0  01-01-2016  04-04-2015           1  Thing1  01-01-2016  04-04-2015   
1  01-01-2016  04-04-2015           1  Thing1  03-03-2015  05-04-2015   
2  03-03-2015  05-04-2015           1  Thing1  01-01-2016  04-04-2015   
3  03-03-2015  05-04-2015           1  Thing1  03-03-2015  05-04-2015   
4  02-02-2015  03-03-2014           1  Thing2  02-02-2015  03-03-2014   
5  02-02-2015  03-03-2014           1  Thing2  03-03-2015  07-03-2015   
6  03-03-2015  07-03-2015           1  Thing2  02-02-2015  03-03-2014   
7  03-03-2015  07-03-2015           1  Thing2  03-03-2015  07-03-2015   
8  24-03-2016  03-04-2016           0  Thing5  24-03-2016  03-04-2016   
   Quantity_y  
0           1  
1           1  
2           1  
3           1  
4           1  
5           1  
6           1  
7           1  
8           0
```

then filer is as you like:

```
merged_data[(...) & (...)]
```

Comment: (it's not a complete solution because it's not clear what exactly you need, but getting from this to a full solution should be simple)